# play multiple audio files sequentially under the restrictions of if else conditions

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to play multiple audio files sequentially under the restrictions of if else conditions
I cant use javascript's ended/event function 
since it is not sure whether first audio will play or not
it will play only if the condition is true 
Both sounds are getting played simultaneously and its getting mixed up

I also cant use the delay or sleep function since if the condition 1st is not true and the first file doesnt play ,
the second one should play without any delay

```
<?php
    $y=3;
    $z=4;
    $audio1="bflat.mp3";
    $audio2="SUUCgrcp.mp3";
    if($z==4) {
        echo"<embed src =\"$audio1\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
    }
    if($y==3) {
        echo"<embed src =\"$audio2\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not use the `else` statement? So that only one audio will be played at any given time

Comment: In that case the second audio will not play even if the condition is true